# PHP MySQL Loop on two-level data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I am trying to extract two layer data from mysql database with a single mysql query and then display it grouped by top-layer with a php while loop.

```
<?php $org = "1";

$row1 = mysqli_prepare($db,"SELECT * FROM menu WHERE org = ? ORDER BY mid DESC"); 
$row1->bind_param("s", $org);
mysqli_stmt_execute($row1); $row2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($row1);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($row2)){ ?>

<div class="category"><?php echo $row["item"]; /* GROUPED*/?>
<div class="item"><?php echo $row["item"]; /* INDIVIDUAL ITEM*/?></div>
</div>

<?php }; ?>
```

| mid | parent | org | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 | Category 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | Item 1 | $10 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Item 2 | $12 |
| 4 |  | 1 | Category 2 |  |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | Item 3 | $12 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 | Item 4 | $90 |

[image: data structure]

Obviously each item will appear only once but also the category will appear as many times as the underlying items. In the code however i need to group all items under the same parent category. Any ideas?

Desired Result

| List |
| --- |
| Category 1 |
| - Item 1 |
| - Item 2 |
| Category 2 |
| - Item 3 |
| - Item 4 |

Or in terms of the HTML code output:

```
<div class="category">Parent Category 1<br>
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>
<div class="category">Parent Category 3<br>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide your data as text please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Why do you think $row["item"] would output different results in the same block?

Comment: Also, what does this line actually do? >>> mysqli_stmt_execute($row1); $row2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($row1);

Comment: @BrokenArrow he wants a flowcontrol  so he can show on e or the other

Comment: @nbk Got the point, somewhat. Well, can't it be done with LIMIT clause fetching two rows to achieve the same with a single execution?

Comment: Maybe even nested foreach loop within the while loop? Or is there something more elegant. I want to have one SQL query and not query for categories first (null parent col) and then for each category query again for the underlying items corresponding to the non-null parent id

Comment: @BrokenArrow no you have to check also parent_id if it is empty

Comment: @stefan999 Do you mean to say N depth? Or just Category > Item relation depth?

Comment: @nbk yes but ideally not with the SQL query - there it would be easier to get everything and then sort and group it with the PHP loops I guess?

Comment: @BrokenArrow For now 2-level only, maybe later 3-levels but not N depth

Comment: So, in one single query, you want a record set that groups all Items in the same row block in mid ASC order being the Category row on top of each Item row block?

Comment: Yes, basically get categories and items together and then group items into corresponding categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flow control to your code

```
<?php 
$org = "1";

$row1 = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM menu WHERE org = ? ORDER BY mid ASC"); 
$row1->bind_param("s", $org);
mysqli_stmt_execute($row1); 
$row2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($row1);
$controlfirst = 0;
while(  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($row2)) {
    if ( !isset($row["parent"])) { 
        if ( $controlfirst == 1) {  ?>          
        </div> 
    <?php } ?>
        <div class="category"><?php echo $row["item"]; /* GROUPED*/ 
     $controlfirst = 1;
    }
    else { 
            ?>
            
            <div class="item"><?php echo $row["item"];?> </div>/* INDIVIDUAL ITEM*/
    <?php  }
 }      
if ( $controlfirst == 1) {  ?>      


    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

See [example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9db59988e035df798d837e44c587ba5e&sqlses=0e023b9d26f85aeaa575b99487accc19&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thanks, but not working as desired. Can you please check my edited question - the desired HTML output code. The top-level category div should encapsulate all underlying items.

Comment: yes i have changed the code a bit for better fit

Comment: Hmmm, i see that for the first category it works fine, but the 2nd and n-th category doesn't have the end </div>

Comment: yes i noticced that too, but it is a   small adjustment

Comment: Thanks, it works... Just to try, how would i implement $controlfirst for 3rd level parent ids? That would mean that 3rd level item has parent_id which points to item where parent_id is not null (so not a category)?

Comment: third level is a hierarchy problem which is difficult in mysql 5.7 and a bit more easy in mysql 8 with recursive cte. with hierarchy i send the people to http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ and then they can try their luck. Eith every hierarchy level you need one additional variable and a logic that control all variables, which gets quite messy, that is why we are happy with mysql 8

Comment: unfortunately I need your help again. I am trying to adapt your script to concatenate multiple 2nd and 3rd level items on one line, but it's not working. I just need to move the linebreak to the last (max mid) with non-null sub id - https://phpize.online/?phpses=7390a28e1550faed2a1872b53fb99742&sqlses=f672247eb0e7dfcc6889a97e7a906bc1&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Your query is a bit off but the php  code should be loke this, https://phpize.online/?phpses=ffd0a3b4d3afca120fff7952d042d0b4&sqlses=3b9f24054483c1337750fe52ae6417a6&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57  but next time ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

This should do it;

```
SELECT          T.*, 
                IF(T.parent IS NULL, T.mid, T.parent) AS ParentGroup
FROM            mytable as T
WHERE           T.org = 1 # Comment out here to get for all org
ORDER BY        T.org ASC, ParentGroup ASC, T.parent IS NULL DESC, T.mid ASC
```

**Note:** Please read the SQL injection policies carefully before using SQL statements with your code.

I hope you already know how to fetch data with PHP from MySQL; once all records are fetched, you can loop through like below;

```
... Here you already fetched all the records from database into $Recordset array

foreach($Recordset as $Data){ // Loop through the record set
    if($Data["parent"]){
        print "<li>{$Data["item"]}</li>"; // Item
    }
    else{
        print "<div class=\"Category\"><h1>{$Data["item"]}</h1><ul class=\"Item\">"; // Category
    }
}

print "</ul></div>";
```

Comment: How about the php loop?

Comment: You fetch all the rows first, for an 'org', then you loop through the records; Use an IF block to check if this is a category 'if($Row["parent"])', BOLD it, otherwise it is an item, regular text :)

Comment: This should now generate the exact copy of what you said DESIRED

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure... The category div should encapsulate all individual items

Comment: That is the HTML/CSS part, you wanted the SQL solution, once you have the data the way you want, you can arrange/show it any way you want!

Comment: Now it will wrap the Category & Item children inside the 'Category' DIV and each Item are list items of the 'Item' UL block. This should explain your last comment/question.